# How to compile RTL8188CUS driver for OrangePi

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile, orange-pi

I want to make my USB WiFi dongle working in OrangePi.
I've downloaded the driver [from Realtek website](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=274&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true) and started to compile it, but got the error:

```
orangepi@OrangePI:~/rtl8188C$ ls -la
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  6 orangepi orangepi  4096 Sep 11  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 orangepi orangepi  4096 Nov  4 23:02 ..
-rwxr--r--  1 orangepi orangepi    64 Sep 11  2013 clean
drwxr-xr-x  3 orangepi orangepi  4096 Sep 11  2013 core
drwxr-xr-x  3 orangepi orangepi  4096 Sep 11  2013 hal
-rwxr--r--  1 orangepi orangepi    54 Sep 11  2013 ifcfg-wlan0
drwxr-xr-x  4 orangepi orangepi  4096 Sep 11  2013 include
-rwxr--r--  1 orangepi orangepi   110 Sep 11  2013 Kconfig
-rwxr--r--  1 orangepi orangepi 17292 Sep 11  2013 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x  3 orangepi orangepi  4096 Sep 11  2013 os_dep
-rwxr--r--  1 orangepi orangepi   423 Sep 11  2013 runwpa
-rwxr--r--  1 orangepi orangepi   294 Sep 11  2013 wlan0dhcp

orangepi@OrangePI:~/rtl8188C$ make
make ARCH=armv7l CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.4.39/build M=/home/orangepi/rtl8188C  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.4.39/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:584: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Here is a content of [makefile](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13107264/) and Kconfig:

```
orangepi@OrangePI:~/rtl8188C$ cat Kconfig 
config RTL8192CU
    tristate "Realtek 8192C USB WiFi"
    depends on USB
    ---help---
      Help message of RTL8192CU
```

And some info about my operating system:

```
orangepi@OrangePI:~/rtl8188C$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
orangepi@OrangePI:~/rtl8188C$ uname -a
Linux OrangePI 3.4.39 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 12 12:02:29 CEST 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Is it a problem of absent linux headers? How to compile the driver?

Btw, I already tried `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` but nothing was found for installation. After running `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` linux-headers-3.19.0-32 was installed, but i didn't solved the issue, `make` stops with same error.

Comment: Are you able to do a top-level kernel build and modules build without the added driver?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. How to check?

Comment: Can't you use newer kernel? Otherwise you might have to backport a lot of stuff I'm afraid.

Comment: @PaulSerikov You can follow the various tutorials around the web on how to configure, build, and install the kernel.  That will help you understand the process.  If you do this you should install it on a secondary machine.  It is possible to build the driver for the currently installed kernel.  The headers would have to match your current kernel exactly.  As Andy says, you may want a newer kernel.  You will have to see what version the OrangePi was designed for.  Sometimes the driver interface to the kernel is changed.

Comment: Ok, will try. Meanwhile a have some progress. I find kernel headers at https://github.com/loboris/OrangePI-Kernel, as it written by main OrangePi developer at [forum](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepibbsen/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=342) it was designed and adapted for 3.4.39 version. I fixed error with absent folder at /lib/modules/3.4.39/build by creating new symlink to downloaded kernel. But now have another problem: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13118164/ . It says me that kernel configuration is invalid